# "Recommend Deletion" button becomes "Delete"

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-delete

I just gained 10k rep so I'm getting used to the changes in UI in places. Perhaps I've never noticed this before, so I may as well point it out.

I click on "Recommend Deletion" on an answer that I feel doesn't contribute. The popup's call to action says "Delete". Wait, I don't have that power, do I? I don't want that kind of power. I just want to recommend it to be deleted. Shouldn't those two buttons have the same text?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EGNF0y0.png]

Comment: Yes, the buttons should match, and yes, once you have 10k you are actually casting a vote to delete on the post rather than just "recommending" it. Or maybe it's 20k... Those weird deletion rules...

Comment: But I'm not outright "Delete"ing the answer. Also, am I going crazy or did the button text actually change after 10k?

Comment: No. It takes at least three Delete votes to actually delete a post. You can't do it on your own.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the button should automatically know when you have the power to cast a real delete *vote* on a post, instead of a delete *recommendation*.

As a 10ker, you can vote to delete questions that have been closed for two days, and you can't vote to delete answers. Therefore, the button's text should be <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> as you state.

And no, you're not going crazy. The text changed.